# What are ways to update ASP.NET page from HttpModule?

Tags: asp.net

I need to update an ASP.NET page from the HttpModule permanently, or from time to time.

Here is the code of IUpdatablePage interface for our page to be updated:

```
    interface IUpdatablePage
    {
       void Update( string value );
    }
```

Here is the code of HttpModule, I imagine, can be:

```
    void IHttpModule.Init( HttpApplication application )
    {
       application.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler( application_PreRequestHandlerExecute );
    }
    void application_PreRequestHandlerExecute( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
       this._Page = ( Page )HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    }

    void HttpModuleProcessing()
    {
       //... doing smth

       IUpdatablePage page = this._Page as IUpdatablePage;
       page.Update( currentVaue );

       //... continue doing smth
    }
```

Here we:

1. save the current request page in _Page,
2. get access to IUpdatablePage interface while processing in HttpModule
3. call Update function passing some currentValue.

Now the page gets the value in Update function.

```cs
    public partial class MyPage: System.Web.Page, IUpdatablePage
    {
       void IUpdatablePage.Update( string value )
       {
          // Here we need to update the page with new value
          Label1.Text = value;
       }
    }
```

The question is what are the ways to transmit this value to the webform controls so that they would immediately show it in browser?

I suppose any way of refreshing the page: using UpdatePanel, Timer, iframe block, javascript etc.

NOTE, that the request from the page is being processed in HttpModule while refresh.
Please, help with code samples (I'm a web-beginner).

Comment: UpdatePanel + Timer sounds ok. What is your issue with this approach?

Comment: I tried this combination too, but, to my surprise, it updates only once after the http request finishes and never while processing. I'm ready to email the full code of the project for details.

Comment: Not necessary, just post some code snippets with the description of the problem and someone will help. Timer should make the page post back everytime the timer ticks so you should have your updates frequently.

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor, for your attention!
Here is just sample:
    
    <asp:Timer ID="timer" OnTick="timer_Tick" runat="server" Interval="500" Enabled="true" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="<%= _value %>" ></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: <!-- language: c# -->
    
     protected string _value = "";
     protected bool updated = false;

     protected void timer_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
     {
         if ( updated )
         {
             updated = false;
             UpdatePanel1.Update();
         }
     }

     void IUpdatablePage.Update( string value )
     {
         _value = value;
         updated = true;
     }

Comment: The Label1 is the updatable control using substition of _value. UpdatePanel is to be updated by timer only if updated flag is set.

But it doesn't update. It is updated only after page request processing finishes in HttpModule. Sorry for misformatting ))

Comment: When is your `HttpModuleProcessing` method called and from where?

Comment: Dear Wiktor, it is called from the BeginRequest event handler in HttpModule. Now I think it is impossible doing so. 
I used another scheme:
I transfer data through the Session[""] named parameters between HttpModule and the Page. Then, the page shows this data at UpdatePanel that is triggered by timer.
Now this problem has been solved, but another appeared:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553461/uploadpanel-hangs-in-opera-firefox-while-long-requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553461/uploadpanel-hangs-in-opera-firefox-while-long-requests)

Answer (score 0):

The way to transfer data between Page and HttpModule is to use Application named static objects, that are identified by session id.
The page is update via UpdatePanel triggered by timer.

The code of HttpModule (simplified):

```cs
public class UploadProcessModule : IHttpModule
{
   public void Init( HttpApplication context )
   {
      context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
   }
   void context_BeginRequest( object sender, EventArgs e )
   {
      HttpContext context = ( ( HttpApplication )sender ).Context;
      if ( context.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null )
      {
          string sessionId = context.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value;
          context.Application["Data_" + sessionId] = new MyClass();
      }
   }
}
```